# How to access all the rest api's in magento

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm trying to build a flutter app from an existing magento store. How can I access the current REST API of the store? (I'm new to magento...)

Comment: It's better to read the Magento dev docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/index.html and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-intro.html

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can access all rest Api's by using swagger. All you have to do is go to following url:
{your website url}/swagger

You will see some list of API's but not all of them, to access all api's you have to enter token in api_key text field.
After adding api_key you will have access to all rest API's.

[to generate new token](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
        $adminData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin@123");

        $ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/demo23/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($adminData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen(json_encode($adminData))));
        $token = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    //For example change your api url below    
        $request = "http://127.0.0.1/demo23/index.php/rest/default/V1/customerGroups/1";
        $ch = curl_init($request);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
        curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

**Hope This Will Help You !!!**